# change “out of stock” text in category pages with any themes woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Hi i am making a plugin that can change the "Out of stock" text. It works well on single product page but in category page is a different story. I heard that Woocommerce doesn't show up "Out of stock" text in category page as default and some themes using this trick to enable the text: http://gasolicious.com/add-stock-status-woocommerce-shop-category-pages/

The problem is this guide insert specific html elements with "Out of stock" text inside so they're different over themes. Is there anyway i can overwrite only the text "Out of sotck" inside those html?

Answer (score 0):

You may try to change the text using woocommerce hook "woocommerce_get_availability".

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_availability', 'custom_get_availability', 1, 2);

function custom_get_availability( $availability, $_product ) {
    //change text "In Stock' to 'SPECIAL ORDER'
    if ( $_product->is_in_stock() ) $availability['availability'] = __('AVAILABLE', 'woocommerce');

    //change text "Out of Stock' to 'SOLD OUT'
    if ( !$_product->is_in_stock() ) $availability['availability'] = __('SOLD OUT', 'woocommerce');
        return $availability;
    }
```

http://www.terrytsang.com/tutorial/woocommerce-change-in-stock-or-out-of-stock-text-in-woocommerce/